# Access individual elements of ChunkedArray by its index within column

Tags: c++, apache-arrow

What is the best method to randomly access individual elements (*"Scalars"*) of `arrow::ChunkedArray` e.g. for testing and display purposes? Is there some equivalent method to `Array::GetScalar` which takes into account that the `ChunkedArray` consists of multiple chunks?

The way I found so far is an own helper function which "searches" the appropriate chunk like this (not tested):

```
std::shared_ptr<arrow::Scalar>
get_scalar(const std::shared_ptr<arrow::ChunkedArray>& chunked_array, int64_t index) {
    auto it = chunked_array->chunks().begin();
    while (index >= (*it)->length()) {
        index -= (*it)->length();
        ++it;
    }
    auto result = (*it)->GetScalar(index);
    if (!result.ok()) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    return result.MoveValueUnsafe();
}
```

But I'm wondering if there is something like this already provided or there is a better practice to do so?

Similar applies to the `arrow::stl::ArrayIterator` - is there an equivalent iterator for `Chunked::Array`?

Comment: It's been 5 (6?) years... Things like this make arrow look... aimless.